# Not able to reproduce results with Tensorflow even with random seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, random-seed

I am training a simple autoencoder in Keras with data I have generated. I am currently running the code inside a Google Colab notebook (in case there is a small chance that might be relevant). To achieve reproducible results, I am currently setting random seeds as I have shown below, but it does not seem to be fully effective:

```
# Choose random seed value 
seed_value = 0

# Set numpy pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
np.random.seed(seed_value)

# Set tensorflow pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
```

The random seed code seems to help with obtaining the same initial weights every time I initialize the model. I can see this using `model.get_weights()` after creating the model (this is the case even when I restart the notebook and re-run the code). However, I am not able to achieve reproducible results in terms of model performance, because the model weights are different each time after training. I assume that the random seed code above accounts for ensuring the data is split and shuffled in the same way each time during training, even though I have not split the training/validation data beforehand (I am instead using `validation_split=0.2`) or specified `shuffle=False` while fitting the model, but perhaps I am incorrect in making that assumption? Additionally, are there any other random seeds I need to include to ensure reproducible results? Here is the code I am using to construct and train the model:

```
def construct_autoencoder(input_dim, encoded_dim):
   # Add input
   input = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

   # Add encoder layer
   encoder = Dense(encoded_dim, activation='relu')(input)

   # Add decoder layer
   # Input contains binary values, hence the sigmoid activation
   decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(encoder)
   model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=decoder)

   return model

autoencoder = construct_autoencoder(10, 6)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
# print(autoencoder.get_weights()) -> This is the same every time, even with restarting the notebook

autoencoder.fit([data,
                 data, 
                 epochs=20, 
                 validation_split=0.2,
                 batch_size=16,
                 verbose=0)

# print(autoencoder.get_weights()) -> This is different every time, but not sure why?
```

If you have any ideas on why I am not getting reproducible results during model training, do let me know. I found this https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development on Keras' website, but not sure if it's relevant for this (and if so, why?). I know there are other questions asking about reproducibility for model training, but I didn't find any of them to address this specific question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 2.x version

this code can reproduce results if you use tf in cpu.

```
seed_value = 42
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
```

But if you use tf in gpu (default), the NVIDIA problem [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12800) will make your results unreproducible even you write `tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)`

So the solution is:

`pip install tensorflow-determinism`

and then use the following code

```
def setup_seed(seed):
    random.seed(seed)  
    np.random.seed(seed) 
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)  # tf cpu fix seed
    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'  # tf gpu fix seed, please `pip install tensorflow-determinism` first


setup_seed(42)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the seeds and the recommendations in the Keras article (they are relevant indeed), you need to make sure that all your versions of the python modules are the same as in the notebook.

Checking the versions of all your modules locally can be easily done with the `pip freeze` command (in the command line interface). Checking within the notebook can be done on a module-by-module basis by e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure that I follow the article. In regards, to the python modules comment, could expand on that please? Thanks!